# WordPress - pre_get_posts in place of query_posts on pages

Tags: php, wordpress

My situation is somewhat complex, I'll try to explain it as succinctly as possible.

I'm currently using `query_posts` to modify the main query on custom pages on my site, which as far as I can tell works quite well, though I've read that using query_posts is bad practice for a number of different reasons.

So, why am I using `query_posts` and not creating a `WP_Query` object you may ask?

It's because I'm using the infinite-scroll plugin, infinite-scroll doesn't play nice with WP_query, but it works absolutely fine when you simply modify the main query with query_posts. For example, pagination doesn't work using infinite scroll + WP_query (main concern).

On one page, I'm modifying the query to get most viewed posts.

```
<?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>     
<?php query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ,  'paged' => $paged, ) ); ?>     


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

    <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
            get_template_part( 'video-post' );
        }elseif ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
            get_template_part( 'image-post' );
        } else {
           get_template_part( 'standard-post' );
        }

    ?>

<?php endwhile;?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So after a lot of reading I gather that my other option to modify the main query is using `pre_get_posts`, though I'm somewhat unsure as to how to go about this.

Take this for example:-

```
function textdomain_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'textdomain_exclude_category' );
```

Alright, so simple enough - if it's the home page, modify the main query and exclude two categories.

What I'm confused about and can't figure out is:-

1. the use case scenario for custom page templates. With my `query_posts` modification I can just drop in the array before `if (have_posts())`, select my page template, publish it and away I go. 
   With `pre_get_posts` I can't figure out how to say for example `$query->most-viewed` etc
2. `array( 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ,  'paged' => $paged, ) );`

How the heck do I do that with `pre_get_posts` and make sure it's paginated, ie. works with infinite scroll? In all the examples I've seen with `pre_get_posts` there's no arrays.

Comment: Sorry I didn't figure out what you want. query_posts, WP_Query, pre_get_posts are all in wp-includes/query.php, query_posts uses WP_Query to do the work, so basically no big difference here. pre_get_posts is just a global hook, modify the $query(passed in by   query_posts($query), but parsed) before doing the real work.

Comment: I don't think infinite scroll has anything to do with your problem. Infinite-scroll plugin uses next-previous page links fetch content. You can setup these links with get_posts also, query_post or whatever you wish.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### How to use the `pre_get_posts` hook to display list of posts on a page, through a custom page template?

I've been playing with the `pre_get_posts` hook and here's one idea

**Step #1:**

Ceate a page called for example *Show* with the slug:

```
example.com/show
```

**Step #2:**

Create a custom page template:

```
tpl_show.php
```

located in the current theme directory.

**Step #3:**

We construct the following `pre_get_posts` action callback:

```
function b2e_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    $target_page = 'show';                             // EDIT to your needs

    if (    ! is_admin()                               // front-end only
         && $query->is_main_query()                    // main query only
         && $target_page === $query->get( 'pagename' ) // matching pagename only
    ) {
        // modify query_vars:
        $query->set( 'post_type',      'post'                 );  // override 'post_type'
        $query->set( 'pagename',       null                   );  // override 'pagename'
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10                     );
        $query->set( 'meta_key',       'wpb_post_views_count' );
        $query->set( 'orderby',        'meta_value_num'       );
        $query->set( 'order',          'DESC'                 );

        // Support for paging
        $query->is_singular = 0;

        // custom page template
        add_filter( 'template_include', 'b2e_template_include', 99 );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'b2e_pre_get_posts' );
```

where

```
function b2e_template_include( $template )
{
    $target_tpl = 'tpl_show.php'; // EDIT to your needs

    remove_filter( 'template_include', 'b2e_template_include', 99 );

    $new_template = locate_template( array( $target_tpl ) );

    if ( ! empty( $new_template ) )
        $template = $new_template; ;

    return $template;
}
```

This should also give us pagination:

```
example.com/show/page/2
example.com/show/page/3
```

etc.

### Notes

I updated the answer and removed the query-object part modification, based on the suggestion from @PieterGoosen, since it could e.g. break the breadcrumbs on his setup.

Also removed the `is_page()` check within the `pre_get_posts` hook, since it might still give some irregularities in some cases. The reason is that the  query-object is not always available. This is being worked on, see e.g. [#27015](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27015).  There are [workarounds possible](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188317/what-is-the-correct-method-for-determining-is-front-page-when-using-filters-su/188320) if we want to use the `is_page()` or `is_front_page()`.

I constructed the following table, just to get a better overview of some of the  *properties* and *query varaiables* of the main `WP_Query` object, for a given slug:

[image: table]

It's [interesting to note](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/294a164b15f22c8c379c2250b52a148f060a3547/wp-includes/query.php#L3175-L3189) that the *pagination* in `WP_Query` depends on the `nopaging` not being set and the current page not being *singular* (from the 4.4 [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/294a164b15f22c8c379c2250b52a148f060a3547/wp-includes/query.php#L3175-L3189)):

```
// Paging
if ( empty($q['nopaging']) && !$this->is_singular ) {
    $page = absint($q['paged']);
    if ( !$page )
        $page = 1;

    // If 'offset' is provided, it takes precedence over 'paged'.
    if ( isset( $q['offset'] ) && is_numeric( $q['offset'] ) ) {
        $q['offset'] = absint( $q['offset'] );
        $pgstrt = $q['offset'] . ', ';
    } else {
        $pgstrt = absint( ( $page - 1 ) * $q['posts_per_page'] ) . ', ';
    }
    $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $pgstrt . $q['posts_per_page'];
}
```

where we can see that the `LIMIT` part of the generated SQL query is within the conditional check. This explains why we modify the `is_singular` property above.

We could have used other filter/hooks, but here we used `pre_get_posts` as mentioned by the OP.

Hope this help.

Comment: This is a great answer and I think it's probably the best I'm going to get, so here's the bounty! It's a shame pre_get_posts isn't more flexible.

Comment: Thanks @andy, it was an interesting puzzle ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this but I can't get posts per page working?? :/ Also, incase permalinks are not on you may also want to do add this:
$query->set( 'page_id', NULL );

Comment: I just could not get `pre_get_posts` to work on a page, Never thought to unset the stuff you referred to in your answer.  Setting the template again was obvious though. I was about to ask a new question on WPSE as I could not find concrete info on this. Strange that I accidentally found this by reading a comment you left to another post which I actually found via google. ;-)

Comment: Will award the bounty to you as soon as I can, unfortunately I cannot award the bounty within 24 hours of starting one. Enjoy ;

Comment: We do not really need to unset the queried object and it's ID and `is_page()`. From testing it seems that we only need `$query->is_singular = 0;` to make everything work. Have you encountered any issues without unsetting the 3 things as you have done. I'm just asking as we can probably use `get_queried_object_id()` to get the page template from the db and then use that in our`template_include` filter to allow the filter being dynamic when we change templates or themes

Comment: I don't recall now why I added these extra ones, but I can't test today but will try to do some testing tomorrow @PieterGoosen

Comment: No problem. Enjoy the rest of your Sunday. Last day to "relax" before everything goes back to normal tommorrow

Comment: Just to give you some feedback on this, unsetting the queried object and `is_page()`actually breaks quite a few things like breadcrumbs and other page related functions. The page is treated as a normal archive then. But again, this all depends on how you would like to use the page. In my case, I would still like to keep basic page functionality, but this does require some extra work which does fall out of scope of this post.  The really helpful part is the `is_singular` part as this helped me a ton in going forward and resolved a few big issues

Comment: Thanks for the update @PieterGoosen and generous bounty. I just updated the answer. I guess I was trying to remove the page identity when I originally posted it, but I've now skipped that part, thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: @birgire I am getting 404 when I try to set this

`$query->set( 'post_type',      'post'                 ); `

Comment: @birgire I got it working; I had to set  `$query->set( 'page_id', null );` Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working and thanks for the update @PareshRadadiya

Answer (score 2):

With inspiration from @birgire answer, I came up with the following idea. (*NOTE: [This is a copy of my answer from this answer over at WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/215027/31545)*)

What I tried to do here was to rather use post injection than completely altering the main query and getting stuck with all the above issues, like directly altering globals, the global value issue and reassigning page templates.

By using post injection, I'm able to keep full post integrity, so  `$wp_the_query->post`, `$wp_query->post`, `$posts` and `$post` stays constant throughout the template, they all only holds the current page object as is the case with true pages. This way, functions like breadcrumbs still think that the current page is a true page and not some kind of archive

I had to alter the main query slightly (*through filters and actions*) to adjust for pagination though, but we will come to that.

### POST INJECTION QUERY

In order to accomplish post injection, I used a custom query to return the posts needed for injection. I also used the custom query's `$found_pages` property to adjust that of the main query to get pagination working from the main query. Posts are injected into the main query through the `loop_end` action.

In order to make the custom query accessible and usable outside the class, I introduced a couple of actions.

- Pagination hooks in order to hook pagination funtions:

  - `pregetgostsforgages_before_loop_pagination`
  - `pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination`
- Custom counter which counts the posts in the loop. These actions can be used to alter how posts are displayed inside the loop according to post number

  - `pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part`
  - `pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part`
- General hook to access the query object and current post object

  - `pregetgostsforgages_current_post_and_object`

These hooks gives you a total hands-off experience as you do not need to change anything in the page template itself, which was my original intention from the start. A page can completely be altered from a plugin or a function file which makes this very dynamic

I have also used `get_template_part()` in order to load a template part which will be used to display the posts on. Most themes today make use of template parts, that makes this very useful in the class. If your theme uses `content.php`, you can simply pass `content` to `$templatePart` to load `content.php`.

If you need post format support for template parts, it is easy, you can still just pass `content` to `$templatePart` and simply set `$postFormatSupport` to `true` and a template part `content-video.php` will be loaded for a post with a post format of `video`

### THE MAIN QUERY

The following changes was done to the main query through the respective filters and actions

- In order to paginate the main query:

  - The injector query's `$found_posts` property value is passes to that of the main query object through the `found_posts` filter
  - Set the value of the user passed parameter `posts_per_page` to the main query through `pre_get_posts`
  - `$max_num_pages` is calculated using the amount of posts in `$found_posts`  and `posts_per_page`. Because `is_singular` is true on pages, it inhibits the  `LIMIT` clause being set. Simply setting `is_singular` to false caused a few issues, so I decided to set the `LIMIT` clause through the `post_limits` filter. I kept the `offset` of the `LIMIT` clause set to `0` to avoid 404's on paged pages

This takes care of pagination and any issue that might arise from the post injection

### THE PAGE OBJECT

The current page object is available to display as a post by using the default loop on the page, separate and on top of the injected posts. If you do not need this, you can simply set `$removePageFromLoop` to true, this will hide the page content from being displayed.

At this stage I'm using CSS to hide the page object through the `loop_start` and `loop_end` actions as I cannot find another way of doing this. The downside with this method is that anything hooked to `the_post` action hook inside the main query will also be hidden by default if you hide the page object.

## THE CLASS

The `PreGetPostsForPages` class can be improved and should be properly namespaced as well Although you can simply drop this in your theme's functions file, it would be better to drop this into a custom plugin.

Use, modify and abuse as you see fit. The code is well commented, so it should be easy to follow and adjust

```
class PreGetPostsForPages
{
    /**
     * @var string|int $pageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $pageID;

    /**
     * @var string $templatePart
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $templatePart;

    /**
     * @var bool $postFormatSupport
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $postFormatSupport;

    /**
     * @var bool $removePageFromLoop
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $removePageFromLoop;

    /**
     * @var array $args
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $args;

    /**
     * @var array $mergedArgs
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $mergedArgs = [];

    /**
     * @var NULL|\stdClass $injectorQuery
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $injectorQuery = NULL;

    /**
     * @var int $validatedPageID
     * @access protected     
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    protected $validatedPageID = 0;

    /** 
     * Constructor method
     *
     * @param string|int $pageID The ID of the page we would like to target
     * @param string $templatePart The template part which should be used to display posts
     * @param string $postFormatSupport Should get_template_part support post format specific template parts
     * @param bool $removePageFromLoop Should the page content be displayed or not
     * @param array $args An array of valid arguments compatible with WP_Query
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */      
    public function __construct( 
        $pageID             = NULL,
        $templatePart       = NULL,
        $postFormatSupport  = false,
        $removePageFromLoop = false,
        $args               = [] 
    ) {
        $this->pageID             = $pageID;
        $this->templatePart       = $templatePart;
        $this->postFormatSupport  = $postFormatSupport;
        $this->removePageFromLoop = $removePageFromLoop;
        $this->args               = $args;
    }

    /**
     * Public method init()
     *
     * The init method will be use to initialize our pre_get_posts action
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // Initialise our pre_get_posts action
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', [$this, 'preGetPosts'] );
    }

    /**
     * Private method validatePageID()
     *
     * Validates the page ID passed
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private function validatePageID()
    {
        $validatedPageID = filter_var( $this->pageID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        $this->validatedPageID = $validatedPageID;
    }

    /**
     * Private method mergedArgs()
     *
     * Merge the default args with the user passed args
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    private function mergedArgs()
    {
        // Set default arguments
        if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
            $currentPage = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
            $currentPage = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        $default = [
            'suppress_filters'    => true,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'paged'               => $currentPage,
            'posts_per_page'      => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // Set posts per page here to set the LIMIT clause etc
            'nopaging'            => false
        ];    
        $mergedArgs = wp_parse_args( (array) $this->args, $default );
        $this->mergedArgs = $mergedArgs;
    }

    /**
     * Public method preGetPosts()
     *
     * This is the callback method which will be hooked to the 
     * pre_get_posts action hook. This method will be used to alter
     * the main query on the page specified by ID.
     *
     * @param \stdClass WP_Query The query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function preGetPosts( \WP_Query $q )
    {
        if (    !is_admin() // Only target the front end
             && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
             && $q->is_page( filter_var( $this->validatedPageID, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) ) // Only target our specified page
        ) {
            // Remove the pre_get_posts action to avoid unexpected issues
            remove_action( current_action(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

            // METHODS:
            // Initialize our method which will return the validated page ID
            $this->validatePageID();
            // Initiale our mergedArgs() method
            $this->mergedArgs();
            // Initiale our custom query method
            $this->injectorQuery();

            /**
             * We need to alter a couple of things here in order for this to work
             * - Set posts_per_page to the user set value in order for the query to
             *   to properly calculate the $max_num_pages property for pagination
             * - Set the $found_posts property of the main query to the $found_posts
             *   property of our custom query we will be using to inject posts
             * - Set the LIMIT clause to the SQL query. By default, on pages, `is_singular` 
             *   returns true on pages which removes the LIMIT clause from the SQL query.
             *   We need the LIMIT clause because an empty limit clause inhibits the calculation
             *   of the $max_num_pages property which we need for pagination
             */
            if (    $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'] 
                 && true !== $this->mergedArgs['nopaging']
            ) {
                $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'] );
            } elseif ( true === $this->mergedArgs['nopaging'] ) {
                $q->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
            }

            // FILTERS:
            add_filter( 'found_posts', [$this, 'foundPosts'], PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
            add_filter( 'post_limits', [$this, 'postLimits']);

            // ACTIONS:
            /**
             * We can now add all our actions that we will be using to inject our custom
             * posts into the main query. We will not be altering the main query or the 
             * main query's $posts property as we would like to keep full integrity of the 
             * $post, $posts globals as well as $wp_query->post. For this reason we will use
             * post injection
             */     
            add_action( 'loop_start', [$this, 'loopStart'], 1 );
            add_action( 'loop_end',   [$this, 'loopEnd'],   1 );
        }    
    }    

    /**
     * Public method injectorQuery
     *
     * This will be the method which will handle our custom
     * query which will be used to 
     * - return the posts that should be injected into the main
     *   query according to the arguments passed
     * - alter the $found_posts property of the main query to make
     *   pagination work 
     *
     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return \stdClass $this->injectorQuery
     */
    public function injectorQuery()
    {
        //Define our custom query
        $injectorQuery = new \WP_Query( $this->mergedArgs );

        $this->injectorQuery = $injectorQuery;

        return $this->injectorQuery;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method foundPosts()
     * 
     * We need to set found_posts in the main query to the $found_posts
     * property of the custom query in order for the main query to correctly 
     * calculate $max_num_pages for pagination
     *
     * @param string $found_posts Passed by reference by the filter
     * @param stdClass \WP_Query Sq The current query object passed by refence
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $found_posts
     */
    public function foundPosts( $found_posts, \WP_Query $q )
    {
        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return $found_posts;

        remove_filter( current_filter(), [$this, __METHOD__] );

        // Make sure that $this->injectorQuery actually have a value and is not NULL
        if (    $this->injectorQuery instanceof \WP_Query 
             && 0 != $this->injectorQuery->found_posts
        )
            return $found_posts = $this->injectorQuery->found_posts;

        return $found_posts;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method postLimits()
     *
     * We need to set the LIMIT clause as it it is removed on pages due to 
     * is_singular returning true. Witout the limit clause, $max_num_pages stays
     * set 0 which avoids pagination. 
     *
     * We will also leave the offset part of the LIMIT cluase to 0 to avoid paged
     * pages returning 404's
     *
     * @param string $limits Passed by reference in the filter
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $limits
     */
    public function postLimits( $limits )
    {
        $posts_per_page = (int) $this->mergedArgs['posts_per_page'];
        if (    $posts_per_page
             && -1   !=  $posts_per_page // Make sure that posts_per_page is not set to return all posts
             && true !== $this->mergedArgs['nopaging'] // Make sure that nopaging is not set to true
        ) {
            $limits = "LIMIT 0, $posts_per_page"; // Leave offset at 0 to avoid 404 on paged pages
        }

        return $limits;
    }

    /**
     * Public callback method loopStart()
     *
     * Callback function which will be hooked to the loop_start action hook
     *
     * @param \stdClass \WP_Query $q Query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function loopStart( \WP_Query $q )
    {
        /**
         * Although we run this action inside our preGetPosts methods and
         * and inside a main query check, we need to redo the check here aswell
         * because failing to do so sets our div in the custom query output as well
         */

        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return;

        /** 
         * Add inline style to hide the page content from the loop
         * whenever $removePageFromLoop is set to true. You can
         * alternatively alter the page template in a child theme by removing
         * everything inside the loop, but keeping the loop
         * Example of how your loop should look like:
         *     while ( have_posts() ) {
         *     the_post();
         *         // Add nothing here
         *     }
         */
        if ( true === $this->removePageFromLoop )
            echo '<div style="display:none">';
    }   

    /**
     * Public callback method loopEnd()
     *
     * Callback function which will be hooked to the loop_end action hook
     *
     * @param \stdClass \WP_Query $q Query object passed by reference
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function loopEnd( \WP_Query $q )
    {  
        /**
         * Although we run this action inside our preGetPosts methods and
         * and inside a main query check, we need to redo the check here as well
         * because failing to do so sets our custom query into an infinite loop
         */
        if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
            return;

        // See the note in the loopStart method  
        if ( true === $this->removePageFromLoop )
            echo '</div>';

        //Make sure that $this->injectorQuery actually have a value and is not NULL
        if ( !$this->injectorQuery instanceof \WP_Query )
            return; 

        // Setup a counter as wee need to run the custom query only once    
        static $count = 0;    

        /**
         * Only run the custom query on the first run of the loop. Any consecutive
         * runs (like if the user runs the loop again), the custom posts won't show.
         */
        if ( 0 === (int) $count ) {      
            // We will now add our custom posts on loop_end
            $this->injectorQuery->rewind_posts();

            // Create our loop
            if ( $this->injectorQuery->have_posts() ) {

                /**
                 * Fires before the loop to add pagination.
                 *
                 * @since 1.0.0
                 *
                 * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                 */
                do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_before_loop_pagination', $this->injectorQuery );


                // Add a static counter for those who need it
                static $counter = 0;

                while ( $this->injectorQuery->have_posts() ) {
                    $this->injectorQuery->the_post(); 

                    /**
                     * Fires before get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param int $counter (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part', $counter );

                    /**
                     * Fires before get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery-post Current post object (passed by reference).
                     * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_current_post_and_object', $this->injectorQuery->post, $this->injectorQuery );

                    /** 
                     * Load our custom template part as set by the user
                     * 
                     * We will also add template support for post formats. If $this->postFormatSupport
                     * is set to true, get_post_format() will be automatically added in get_template part
                     *
                     * If you have a template called content-video.php, you only need to pass 'content'
                     * to $template part and then set $this->postFormatSupport to true in order to load
                     * content-video.php for video post format posts
                     */
                    $part = '';
                    if ( true === $this->postFormatSupport )
                        $part = get_post_format( $this->injectorQuery->post->ID ); 

                    get_template_part( 
                        filter_var( $this->templatePart, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ), 
                        $part
                    );

                    /**
                     * Fires after get_template_part.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     *
                     * @param int $counter (passed by reference).
                     */
                    do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part', $counter );

                    $counter++; //Update the counter
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();

                /**
                 * Fires after the loop to add pagination.
                 *
                 * @since 1.0.0
                 *
                 * @param \stdClass $this->injectorQuery Current object (passed by reference).
                 */
                do_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination', $this->injectorQuery );
            }
        }

        // Update our static counter
        $count++;       
    }
}
```

### USAGE

You can now initiate the class (*also in your plugin or functions file*) as follow to target the page with ID 251 on which we will show 2 posts per page from the `post` post type

```
$query = new PreGetPostsForPages(
    251,       // Page ID we will target
    'content', //Template part which will be used to display posts, name should be without .php extension 
    true,      // Should get_template_part support post formats
    false,     // Should the page object be excluded from the loop
    [          // Array of valid arguments that will be passed to WP_Query/pre_get_posts
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    ] 
);
$query->init();
```

### ADDING PAGINATION AND CUSTOM STYLING

As I said, there are a few actions in the injector query in order to add pagination or custom styling. Here I added pagination after the loop using [my own pagination function from the linked answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545). Also, using the build in counter, I added a div to to display my posts in two colums.

Here are the actions I used

```
add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_before_template_part', function ( $counter )
{
    $class = $counter%2  ? ' right' : ' left';
    echo '<div class="entry-column' . $class . '">';
});

add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_counter_after_template_part', function ( $counter )
{
    echo '</div>';
});

add_action( 'pregetgostsforgages_after_loop_pagination', function ( \WP_Query $q )
{
    paginated_numbers();    
});
```

Note that pagination is set by the main query, not the injector query, so build-in functions like `the_posts_pagination()` should also work.

This is the end result

[image]

### STATIC FRONT PAGES

Everything works as expected on static front pages together with my pagination function without having to do no modifications

### CONCLUSION

This might seem like a really lot of overheads, and it might be, but the pro's outweigh the con's big time

**BIG PRO'S**

- You do not need to alter the page template for the specific page in any way. This makes everything dynamic and can easily be transferred between themes without making modifications to the code whatsoever if everything is done in a plugin.
- At most, you only need to create a `content.php` template part in your theme if your theme does not have one yet
- Any pagination that works on the main query will work on the page without any type of alteration or anything extra from the query being passed to function.

There are more pro's which I cannot think of now, but these are the important ones

I hope this will help someone in future

Comment: Pieter, have you gotten a `meta_query` to work with this solution? I am trying to find only posts with a certain meta value but have not had success thus far. Passing the `meta_query` as one of the arguments in `PreGetPostsForPages()` does not seem to be working.

Comment: Delightful answer. Ran the code and noticed the following: 
`preGetPosts` method checks for `validatedPageID` in the opening conditional. `$this->validatedPageID` isn't set - via method `$this->validatePageID()` - until after the conditional has run.