# wordpress - pre_get_posts to modify query on specific page?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use pre_get_posts hook to target/modify the query on a specific page?

Currently using query_posts to do this :- `<?php query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'epicredrank', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' ,  'paged' => $paged, ) ); ?>`

Trying to do the same thing with a pre_get_posts hook and it doesn't seem to be working. I was under the impression that it was indeed possible to target a specific page with pre_get_posts but perhaps I'm just doing it wrong?

```
function wpeddit_order($query) { 
if(is_page('id=2439')){ 
   $query->set('meta_key', 'epicredrank'); 
   $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num'); 
   $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
} 
return $query; 
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpeddit_order');
```

Answer (score 1):

#### From the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Page_Requests):

> pre_get_posts cannot be used to alter the query for Page requests (page templates) because 'is_page', 'is_singular', 'pagename' and other properties (depending if pretty permalinks are used) are already set by the parse_query() method.

Comment: Argh, so query_posts is probably the only way to do it?

Comment: `query_posts` is not the preferred method, however; making a `new WP_Query` or using `get_posts` is, I believe, preferred.

Comment: How would one do the same thing with get_posts?

Comment: Here's the [doc page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). You can do that using the `$args` array and setting the `meta_key` and `orderby` values.

Comment: Well, you can actually overwrite it for page requests, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087311/wordpress-pre-get-posts-in-place-of-query-posts-options-changes/22142984#22142984).